# Change ID not found when Change ID is in the correct location

Tags: git, gerrit

I am trying to push in gerrit with the following commit message:

```
Changed some of the packing code for the PLC protocol packet handler.

Change-Id: Ib1e939c444d0c6750955bcd5414ce1cb6f95093a
```

I get the following error from git/gerrit:

> remote: ERROR: missing Change-Id in commit message footer
>
> remote: Hint: A potential Change-Id was found, but it was not in the footer (last paragraph) of the commit message.

So the change ID **is** in the last paragraph (unless there are some funny charactes that i cannot select underneath it). **Why am i not able to push this?**

Note: I can easily work around this, if I switch to another branch and cherry pick this exact commit, i can push correctly. This leads me to believe there is something wrong with the branch??

Comment: Are there additional commits being pushed, and if so, is their format ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you're pushing more than one commit to Gerrit at the same time. Remember that ALL new commits in your branch will be pushed to Gerrit. Execute a "git log" command and check how many of the last commits are new and if they all have Change-Id in the commit message.

What Gerrit version are you using? The Gerrit 2.13 has improved the error message to prevent this kind of issue. See the "Issue 4488" solution at [here](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/releases/2.13.md#Bugfixes).